# Is there a way to follow through with a mouse over, so that it's not so fidgety?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent, mouseover

I'm using the following code

```
$(function() {
$("#page-flip").mouseover(function() { 
    $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
    $(".films").toggleClass("films-change");
    $(".synopsis").toggleClass("synopsis-change");
```

Which works well, but being a mouseover it's a lot more tentative than a click.  I would like that when the mouseover is triggered for it to fully complete, and for it to be inactive for like 5 seconds or something immediately after.  Basically the goal is that the action doesn't flinch at all.  Thanks to any ideas?

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide some more detail, or an example.

Answer (score 1):

add some variable like "var flipDelay=false"

```
$("#page-flip").mouseover(function() { 
   if (!flipDelay) {
    flipDelay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){flipDelay=false},5000)
    //do stuff
   }
})
```

Comment: or unbind mouseover, and bind back in 5 seconds